# "More" overlay of extra tabs in react-navigation and BottomTabs - how to?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In my app, I use `react-navigation` (v5) and have a `BottomTabNavigator` with all my main screens.

I want to make sure that additional tabs (more than 5) are hidden in a special "more" tab which opens a list of the screens - and from there, they should behave like normal tabs, but only shown when the "more" tab is activated.

Here's how the designer imagined it. (Ignore the red counter)

How would you implement something like this using the options of `react-navigation` without too much custom code or external dependencies?

[image: Example of UI]

Comment: Have you tried coding it up just as it appears here? Where the component of the "Mere" tab is a button that opens up a little modal.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of doing that. I've already implemented the TabBar so it looks and behaves like the original one, but when I try `useState()` for having a state of the overlay, it fails telling me that hooks are not allowed in this component.

Comment: Got it fixed - I needed to specify tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />} in order to get rid of this error

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question because I'm facing the same issue. I've managed to do it, but I'm not satisfied with my solution. Since there haven't been any other answers for some time, have you find a better solution?

My approach is to prevent the screen from opening when clicking on a tab bar and instead open a menu. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
function GeneralTabs() {
  const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false)
  return(
  <>
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    initialRouteName="Myheder"
    >
    //other Tab.Screens
    <Tab.Screen
      name="More"
      component={() => null}
      listeners={() => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          setIsMenuVisible(true)
        }
      })}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
          return(
            <MaterialIcons name="more-horiz" color={color} size={size}/>
          )
        }
      }}
    />

    <Menu
      visible={isMenuVisible}
      onDismiss={() => setIsMenuVisible(false)}
      anchor={{x: 0, y: 0}}
    >
      <Menu.Item leadingIcon="account-circle" onPress={() => {/* navigation to my account */}} title="My account" />
      <Menu.Item leadingIcon="tune" onPress={() => {/* navigation to settings */}} title="Settings" />
    </Menu>
  </>
)
```

**UPDATE:**

I guess better solution is to create [custom navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/#built-in-navigators). Main difference is that you redefine appearance and behavior of bottom navigator by passing tabBar prop to a Tab.Navigator.

Here is example that I like more then previous solution:

```
const routeMapping: Record<
  string,
  { icon: string; component: React.ComponentType<any> }
> = {
  Meetings: {
    icon: 'voice-chat',
    component: MeetingsNavigator,
  },
  Chat: {
    icon: 'chat',
    component: Chat,
  },
  More: {
    icon: 'more-horiz',
    component: MoreNullComponent,
  },
}


function GeneralTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Meetings"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarLabelPosition: 'below-icon',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
          return (
            <MaterialIcons
              name={routeMapping[route.name].icon}
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          )
        },
      })}
      tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}
    >
      {Object.keys(routeMapping).map((routeName) => (
        <Tab.Screen
          key={routeName}
          name={routeName}
          component={routeMapping[routeName].component}
        />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

And your TabBar component might looks like:

```
    import { type BottomTabBarProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
    import { Menu } from 'react-native-paper'
    import BottomBarButton from '../components/BottomBarButton'

    export default function TabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }: BottomTabBarProps) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        {state.routes.map((route: any, index: number) => {
            const { options } = descriptors[route.key]
            const isFocused = state.index === index
            const iconNode = options.tabBarIcon?.({
            focused: isFocused,
            color: isFocused ? 'blue' : 'gray',
            size: 20,
            })

            if (route.name == 'More') {
            const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
            return (
                <View key={index}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={index}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setIsVisible(true)
                        }}
                    >
                    <Menu
                        visible={isVisible}
                        onDismiss={() => {
                        setIsVisible(false)
                        }}
                        anchor={
                        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                            <BottomBarButton icon={iconNode} label={route.name} />
                        </View>
                        }
                    >
                        <Menu.Item leadingIcon="account-circle" title="My account"/>
                        <Menu.Item leadingIcon="logout" onPress={() => {}} title="Logout" />
                    </Menu>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
            }

            const onPress = () => {
            const event = navigation.emit({
                type: 'tabPress',
                target: route.key,
                canPreventDefault: true,
            })

            if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                navigation.navigate(route.name)
            }
            }

            return (
            <View key={index}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                    <BottomBarButton icon={iconNode} label={route.name}/>
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            )
        })}
        </View>
    )
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 50,
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: 'lightgray',
    },

    iconContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    })
```

Results are here:
[image]